# Does gcc automatically use -j4? Is there anything I can do to optimize my compilation?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization

Hello I am a beginner with Linux platform therefore I am not familiar with the terminal commands.

I am writing an application on C++ and I expect it to consume a lot of processing power. So I want to make sure I am using all available cores on my device (it has 4 cores).

I am using the following to create an executable file:

```
gcc -o blink -l rt blink.c -l bcm2835
```

where bcm2835 is the library I use for I/O. So my question is, is this command is using all available cores or is there anything I can do to optimize it? I am willing to use everything available, to throw the kitchen sink if it will make this code run faster.

Comment: `make -j4` does not make your code use multiple cores, it makes the build system use multiple cores.

Comment: I see, I'll remove it from the question then. So my question remains as: am I using all cores when I run a code, and if not, is there anything I can do to make sure this happens.

Comment: If you want to utilize multiple cores you need to look into multithreading, which I think is too broad of a topic to be covered in one SO question.

Comment: I see. I will do so, thanks.

Comment: Notice that if your code is IO bound throwing in multithreading is not going to help at all. As always, first reason on the problem at hand and *measure* to understand and fix the performance bottlenecks. Incidentally, you are compiling with optimizations disabled, which means that your CPU-bound code is going several times slower for no reason. Use `-O3`.

Comment: I am going to use this for real time image processing, so it will probably help during the processing part not when I play with I/O. What does `-03` do? Do I just `gcc -o blink -l rt blink.c -l bcm2835 -03`?

Comment: @OE1: that's an "O", not a zero; typically you put it at the start of the command line. If it's missing, the compiler generates a quite naive translation of the C++ code to machine mode (that however is useful in debugging, as it's easier to map source lines to the generated code); enabling optimizations, the compiler performs all kind of magic (inlining, expression folding, better registers usage, automatic vectorization, dead code elimination, instructions reordering to better exploit pipelines, ...) to the code so to make it run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-j` jobs option is for `make` not `gcc`

When used with `make` it will cause multiple "recipes" to be executed in parallel. In this context, your `gcc` line is one recipe.

AFTER QUESTION REVISION

If you want your code to use multiple cores, you will need to use threads or processes. Look into pthreads.

Comment: I see, I removed the make part it was just an example. I am wondering if there is a similar process for entire code execution. Or does OS automatically dedicates all codes once it is executed? I just want to make sure I am using everything available.

Comment: Your os is absolutely not able to "just make your code run on multiple cpu's". Nor is any other system. You need to modify your code so that it uses threads.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, you have this nice-enough crossplatform-enough thread library integrated for you (>=C++11).

Just make sure to add `-std=c++11` so that

```
gcc -o blink -l rt blink.c -l bcm2835
```

becomes

```
gcc -std=c++11 -o blink -l rt blink.c -l bcm2835
```

Docs and basic examples at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/
Nicer looking docs at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

You still have to program what to thread on your own though.